# How to perform classification if you had to use linear regression?

Tags: regression, classification, multiple-regression

If you had to use linear regression for classification, how would you achieve this?

Comment: check this question. I even have the code there. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326350/what-is-happening-here-when-i-use-squared-loss-in-logistic-regression-setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you had to use linear regression for classification, how would you achieve this?

See also the [Binary data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Binary_data) section of GLM on wiki particularly the Identity link section and the link to [Linear probability model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_probability_model). The way you can make a fit with linear link function in R is

```
# simulate data
set.seed(10162295)
options(digits = 5, nwarnings = 5)
n <- 1000
x <- runif(n, -.5, .5)
y <- 0.5 + x > runif(n)

# fit model
fit <- glm(
  y ~ x, binomial("identity"), start = c(0.5, 0), mustart = rep(.5, n))
#R> Warning messages:
#R> 1: step size truncated: out of bounds 
#R> 2: step size truncated: out of bounds 
#R> 3: step size truncated: out of bounds 
#R> 4: step size truncated: out of bounds 
#R> 5: step size truncated: out of bounds 
summary(fit)
#R>  
#R> Call:
#R> glm(formula = y ~ x, family = binomial("identity"), start = c(0.5, 
#R>     0), mustart = rep(0.5, n))
#R> 
#R> Deviance Residuals: 
#R>    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
#R> -2.492  -0.823  -0.080   0.810   2.921  
#R> 
#R> Coefficients:
#R>             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#R> (Intercept)  0.49887    0.00703      71   <2e-16 ***
#R> x            0.99907    0.01407      71   <2e-16 ***
#R> ---
#R> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#R> 
#R> (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
#R> 
#R>     Null deviance: 1386.04  on 999  degrees of freedom
#R> Residual deviance:  973.94  on 998  degrees of freedom
#R> AIC: 977.9
#R> 
#R> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 25
#R>
```

You can make prediction for new observations using the `predict` method where the `newdata` argument contains the new observations.

Do also see the [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326350/what-is-happening-here-when-i-use-squared-loss-in-logistic-regression-setting) that @hxd1011 links to.