# When setting a treshold to use Logistic Regression for a classification task isn't it the same thing as using Linear Regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, classification, linear-model

In a classification task if we don't care about the exact value of the propabality of the a data point belonging to a class or not, but instead just compare it to a treshold (e.g 0.5) to get a discrete classsification, we just need to check if the input $z = b_{0}+∑(b_{i}X_{i})$ of the sigmoid fucntion $g(z)$ of the Logistic Regression  is greater than or equal to zero, that is:

$$
g(z) ≥ 0.5, \text{if z ≥ 0}
$$

But, to me this seems to be the exact same thing as training a Linear Regression model and simply checking if the output $Y$ of the model is greater than or equal to zero, if that's the case, why do we need the sigmoid function at all?

Comment: This has been discussed at great length on this site on numerous topics.  Briefly, use of thresholds in this context is invalid.  A meaningful threshold can only be obtained if you already possess a utility/loss/cost function to measure consequences of decisions.  Stick with predicted probabilities as continuous measures.

Comment: You've discovered that  you can make **inferences** on the logit scale: because $\sigma$ is monotonic increasing and injective, you know that the ordering of values on one scale is the same on the other scale.  But this doesn't mean that logistic regression is superfluous: compared to OLS regression, logistic regression produces different parameter estimates for $b_j$, so OLS makes different predictions. See: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326350/what-is-happening-here-when-i-use-squared-loss-in-logistic-regression-setting/326381#326381

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ALMOST**

Remember what a logistic regression is.

$$
\log\bigg(
\dfrac{\hat p}{1-\hat p}
\bigg) = X\hat\beta
$$

When $\hat p =0.5$, $
\log\bigg(
\dfrac{\hat p}{1-\hat p}
\bigg) = 0
$.

Consequently, if you want to classify based on a threshold of $0.5$, you only need to examine the $X\hat\beta$ portion and check if that value if greater than or less than zero. You can do something similar for any other threshold $\tau$ by calculating $
\log\bigg(
\dfrac{\tau}{1-\tau}
\bigg)
$ and comparing that value to $X\hat\beta$.

The $\hat\beta$ that you calculate for your logistic regression, however, will be different from what you calculate in a linear model, so what you wrote in the question title is not *quite* correct.

However, the predicted probabilities provide valuable information that you lose when you round them to categorical classifications.